# Pundit: Proper way to gain access based on joiner table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

A bit new to Pundit. I have 3 models and a joiner table; a `User`, `Customer` and `Route` model, and a joiner table that allows users to have a route. Customers belongs to specific routes.

I just want authorize a user to see a customer if she/he has a route in the `routes_users` joiner table.

I found myself a lot of ways to do that. But, what the *best* way to achieve it?

*customer_policy.rb*

```
def show?
  if user.admin? || user.sales_manager?
    true
  else
    user.routes.map(&:id).include? record.route_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **.map** is not a good idea as it will populate all routes from DB in order to search through them locally, the best is to use `.where` and not `.map` as below:

```
def show?
  if user.admin? || user.sales_manager?
    true
  else
    user.routes.where(record.route_id).count > 0
  end
end
```